# KOGrids - Different Height on Same Page

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, kogrid

Please excuse if this is a daft question - I am CSS clueless!

I have two ko grids on the same page. I'd like to be able have a different height for grid 1 compared to grid 2. Unfortunately, it seems the height cannot be set from the standard configuration options for ko grid: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/Configuration

From my example at: http://jsfiddle.net/BizTalkers/L0ce5jmy/2/ I've found that I can change the height by editing:

```
#wrapper{
height:400px;
}
```

In my real application, the ko grid is displayed in a Razor view of an asp.net MVC website. I've found I can adjust the height of all ko grids by changing the height property in the following:

```
/******** Viewport ********/
.kgViewport{
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 20px;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

What would be the best way to adjust the height of the grids independently?